# Simplify Data filtering using pandas function

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys I am quite new on creating function in Python. How can I simplify this process of filtering data based on Year using a function?

```
df_2013 = df_train1[df_train1['year']== 2013][['month','sales']]
df_2013 = df_2013.groupby('month').agg({'sales':'mean'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'sales':'s13'})
df_2014 = df_train1[df_train1['year']== 2014][['month','sales']]
df_2014 = df_2014.groupby('month').agg({'sales':'mean'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'sales':'s14'})
df_2015 = df_train1[df_train1['year']== 2015][['month','sales']]
df_2015 = df_2015.groupby('month').agg({'sales':'mean'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'sales':'s15'})
df_2016 = df_train1[df_train1['year']== 2016][['month','sales']]
df_2016 = df_2016.groupby('month').agg({'sales':'mean'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'sales':'s16'})
df_2017 = df_train1[df_train1['year']== 2017][['month','sales']]
df_2017 = df_2017.groupby('month').agg({'sales':'mean'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'sales':'s17'})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using lists or dicts and avoid separate, similarly structured objects in global environment. Doing so, you keep your code DRY (**D**on't **R**repeat **Y**ourself) by applying same methods on elements of dictionary or list.

```py
# DEFINED METHOD TO ENCAPSULATE ALL OPERATIONS
def build_aggregate_frame(year_param):
    agg_df = (
        df_train1.query("year == @year_param")
          .groupby("month", as_index= False)
          .agg({"sales": "mean"})
          .rename(columns={"sales": f"s{year_param[-2:]}"})
    )

    return agg_df

# DICTIONARY OF AGGREGATED DATA FRAMES
train_year_df_dict = {
    str(year): build_aggregate_frame(year) for year in range(2013, 2018)
}

# ACCESS INDIVIDUAL YEAR DATA TRAMES
train_year_df_dict["2013"]
train_year_df_dict["2014"]
...
train_year_df_dict["2017"]
```